# how can i add box layout both in horizontally and vertical like gridview in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want add dynamic layout in android.this layout should be in horizontally and vertically.like[image]

like gridview

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: no code i want to create layout like youtube i have cretae potrat mode layout like youtube but lanscap mode layout i don't no how to create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same requirement and I Solved my problem by using **FlowLayout**. Sample code and references are available [on github](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) Its simple to use. 
Hope this'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Linerlayout with property    `android:orientation="vertical"` for verical button and    `android:orientation="horizontal"` for horizontal buttons.
Also use weight property of linerLayout

Answer (score 0):

use nested Linear Layouts and change the orientation property .Check this library it might be helpful

https://github.com/Comcast/FreeFlow